How to get PowerShell current directory by PID in Java?
I need to get PowerShell current directory in Java code using PowerShell PID. For example, if there is a PowerShell instance and a user is in E:\Temp directory I need to get E:\Temp. If the user does cd Foo, I need to get E:\Temp\Foo.
This is my code:
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {

    public interface NtDll extends StdCallLibrary {
        NtDll INSTANCE = com.sun.jna.Native.load("ntdll", NtDll.class);

        class PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION extends Structure {
            public int ExitStatus;
            public Pointer PebBaseAddress;
            public IntByReference AffinityMask;
            public int BasePriority;
            public IntByReference UniqueProcessId;
            public IntByReference InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;

            @Override
            protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
                return Arrays.asList("ExitStatus", "PebBaseAddress", "AffinityMask", "BasePriority",
                        "UniqueProcessId", "InheritedFromUniqueProcessId");
            }
        }

        int NtQueryInformationProcess(WinNT.HANDLE ProcessHandle, int ProcessInformationClass,
                PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION ProcessInformation, int ProcessInformationLength, IntByReference ReturnLength);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pid = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
        String currentDirectory = getProcessCurrentDirectory(pid);
        System.out.println("Current Directory: " + currentDirectory);
    }

    public static String getProcessCurrentDirectory(int pid) {
        WinNT.HANDLE processHandle =
                Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(Kernel32.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | Kernel32.PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pid);
        if (processHandle == null) {
            System.err.println("Failed to open process");
            return null;
        }

        NtDll.PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi = new NtDll.PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION();
        IntByReference retLen = new IntByReference();
        NtDll.INSTANCE.NtQueryInformationProcess(processHandle, 0, pbi, pbi.size(), retLen);

        Pointer pebAddress = pbi.PebBaseAddress;
        Pointer processParametersPointer = pebAddress.share(0x20);

        Pointer rtlUserProcParamsAddress = readPointer(processHandle, processParametersPointer);
        Pointer currentDirectoryPointer = rtlUserProcParamsAddress.share(0x38);

        int directoryLength = readShort(processHandle, currentDirectoryPointer.share(0x10));
        Pointer directoryPointer = readPointer(processHandle, currentDirectoryPointer.share(0x08));

        int bufferSize = Math.max(directoryLength + 2, 256);
        Memory buffer = new Memory(bufferSize);
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, directoryPointer, buffer, (int) buffer.size(), null);

        String directory = buffer.getWideString(0);
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return directory;
    }

    private static Pointer readPointer(WinNT.HANDLE processHandle, Pointer address) {
        Memory buffer = new Memory(Native.POINTER_SIZE);
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, (int) buffer.size(), null);
        return buffer.getPointer(0);
    }

    private static int readShort(WinNT.HANDLE processHandle, Pointer address) {
        Memory buffer = new Memory(2); // size of short
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, (int) buffer.size(), null);
        return buffer.getShort(0);
    }
}

My code works only for CMD. However, it doesn't work for PowerShell always showing same initial directory (I tested in Windows 7). Could anyone say how to do it for PowerShell, if it is possible?

"However, it doesn't work for PowerShell always showing same initial directory" - that's expected, PowerShell 2.0 doesn't update [Environment]::CurrentDirectory when you change location. Try explicitly setting [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = "C:\some\existing\path" in PowerShell and run your java program again

There's nothing to fix, it's by-design behavior - 1 host process can host multiple runspaces, so there's no unambiguous "primary working directory".

@MathiasR.Jessen ChatGPT says it was fixed in 3.0, but I can' test as I have only Win 7 as I use Linux

Why are you arguing with me if ChatGPT has all the answers? :) FWIW behavior is still the same in Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.4.3 on Windows

@MathiasR.Jessen I don't argue with you :) I simply got too many wrong answers from ChatGPT so I need to be sure when I can't test. I am really very thankful for your help.

Can you tell us more about the use case? Why is it important to fetch the current location of a given PowerShell host process? What if the user has changed location to a non-FileSystem provider in their PowerShell session, what do you wanna do then?

@MathiasR.Jessen We use JediTermFX. This is a terminal emulator for Java[FX]. So, it can be used in any OS. The problem is that we can't find a way to get current directory for Windows PowerShell. For example, it can be required if a user wants to split terminal, so we need to get his current directory to create a new terminal with the same location.
